# Boot Camp assistant doesn't restart to the Windows installer

Tags: macos, windows-10, mac, multi-boot, boot-camp

I tried Boot Camp but unfortunately, it did not restart to the Windows installation screen as it said it would. I'm stuck now. When I open  Boot Camp Assistant now, it doesn't let me progress, noting that I don't have enough space.

Here is what my Disk Utility says:

[Image of Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLBbY.png)

[Image of Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK1fK.png)

Here is the output of `diskutil list`:

```
    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            120.5 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +80.0 GB    disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 7EB1EDB1-EDA6-4E40-B823-396E69091985
                                 Unlocked Encrypted
```

I have no idea what to do.

My model is: MacBook Air 13" (2015)

Comment: Need more info. Can you still use the mac? I if you can you may need to undo boot camp & delete the partition, then make some space on your main mac disk then try boot camp again.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Hi mac automatically starts osx. Even when I hold option key, there is only one startup option.